# return type of interface

Tags: java, interface

I have the following code:

```
public interface PlotterRepository {
  //methods definitions
}

public interface RepositorySelector {
  public PlotterRepository getPlotterRepository();
}

public class PlotManager {
  static private RepositorySelector repositorySelector;

  static public PlotterRepository getPlotterRepository() {
    if (repositorySelector == null) {
      // few lines of code
    }
    return repositorySelector.getPlotterRepository();
  }
}

public class DefaultRepositorySelector implements RepositorySelector {

    final PlotterRepository repository;

    public DefaultRepositorySelector(PlotterRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public PlotterRepository getPlotterRepository() {
        return repository;
    }
}
```

My only question is how `repositorySelector.getPlotterRepository()` became a type of `PlotterRepository`...?

```
PlotterRepository = repositorySelector.getPlotterRepository()
```

In `PlotManager` the `RepositorySelector`'s interface method is implemented. And in this method `PlotterRepository` is type of interface defined in `PlotterRepository`. Correct me if am wrong and share your words regrading my doubt that how its happening..?

Comment: `PlotterRepository = repositorySelector.getPlotterRepository()`... (How..?)  Because  `public PlotterRepository getPlotterRepository();` The RepositorySelector  returns PlotterRepository.

Comment: @LyjuIEdwinson..could you please explain more..?

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear.

Comment: @shmosel..I just want to understand how PlotterRepository = repositorySelector.getPlotterRepository() is happening in code....? I mean how repositorySelector.getPlotterRepository() is an type of PlotterRepository ..? I hope its clear now...!!

Comment: @LyjuIEdwinson..could you please explain how using an interface with one of its method can become an returning type of an method...?

Comment: @LearnJava I tidied up your question a bit, including removing the filenames, since they don't appear to be relevant to the question. If you're actual question is "*How does the code in these separate files get connected?*" please edit your question so that's clearer. The short answer is "That's what the [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) does".

Comment: `repositorySelector.getPlotterRepository()` 'became a type of' `PlotterRepository` because you defined it that way, and wrote the necessary code. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`repositorySelector` is an instance of `RepositorySelector` (or it's `null`, but I'm assuming the contents of the `if` block set it to some non-null value). Calling `repositorySelector.getPlotterRepository()` invokes the `.getPlotterRepository()` which the `RepositorySelector` defines will return a `PlotterRepository` instance of some sort.

So `repositorySelector.getPlotterRepository()` does not *become* a `PlotterRepository`, it's a method which *returns* a `PlotterRepository`.

This is an example of the [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), having a "factory" (`RepositorySelector`) that can construct instances of a type (`PlotterRepository`) without the code in question needing to know how exactly the factory actually constructs the desired type.

---

> In `PlotManager` the `RepositorySelector`'s interface method is implemented.

That's not actually true - despite the confusing name `PlotManager.getPlotterRepository()` is unrelated to the `RepositorySelector` interface (notice that it doesn't say `implements RepositorySelector`).

---

> repositorySelector is an interface and ... PlotterRepository is ... nothing but just an another interface

Ah, but `repositorySelector` *isn't* an interface :) It's a variable that points to some object that *implements* the `RepositorySelector` interface (if it's not `null`). Any class that implements `RepositorySelector` has to have defined a `getPlotterRepository()` method, and that is what is being called in the line in question - the method defined *in that class*.

This behavior (called [method overriding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding)) is a core tenant of Object Oriented Programming, and a key feature of the Java language.

---

With `DefaultRepositorySelector` you can see it's implementing `RepositorySelector` and therefore implementing `RepositorySelector.getPlotterRepository()`. So (assuming `repositorySelector` has been assigned to an instance of `DefaultRepositorySelector` somewhere in your `// few lines of code` block) `repositorySelector.getPlotterRepository()` will call into that instance's `getPlotterRepository()` method, and return the `PlotterRepository` passed into the `DefaultRepositorySelector`'s constructor.

Comment: @dim0414...I mean how using interface repositorySelector with method getPlotterRepository() producing type of PlotterRepository..? That makes me thinking alot .!! Because repositorySelector is an interface and getPlotterRepository() is a defined method in it and moreover PlotterRepository is just an type used in method name which is nothing but just an another interface...!!

Comment: @LearnJava I've expanded my answer - does that help?

Comment: thanks for sharing but still I don't think it's pointing to my doubt's solution. You said overriding, doesn't seems to be any inherentance in code then how overriding could be done..!! Thats right that repositorySelector is an interface type variable and pointing to an object of class whoever implemented that interface. But still it's not solving a equation.. tea(PlotterRepository) = repositorySelector(tea powder).getPlotterRepository()(water)... How these elements are capable of making an type of PlotterRepository ...? Please share something more ...!!

Comment: @LearnJava somewhere else, other than in the code you've shared, there is a class implementing these interfaces. Can you share the remaining code that sets `repositorySelector`? That is where you should be looking. I've no idea what your `tea(PlotterRepository) = ...` comment is referring to, that's not Java.

Comment: I have updated my question with a code where repositorySelector is implemented..!! Now what you will say..?

Comment: @LearnJava I added a little more. As you can see `DefaultRepositorySelector` is implementing `RepositorySelector`, so I'm not sure what you're still confused about.

Comment: dimo414...okay I get it now ... so it's overriding the method and producing PlotterRepository mentioned in DefaultRepositorySelector.. where it's defined that this method will produce if PlotterRepository type . But how they are overriding the method without inheritance ...?

Comment: What you're looking at *is* inheritance. `DefaultRepositorySelector ` implements (which we could colloquially describe as "is inheriting from") `RepositorySelector` and therefore is a `RepositorySelector`.

Comment: @dimo414...that is correct, I'm just asking how we are able to use getPlotterRepository() method in Class PlotManager directly ? Like we are using RepositorySelector interface's method in DefaultRepositorySelector  because DefaultRepositorySelector  have implemented  RepositorySelector interface. But how in PlotManager how are able to access getPlotterRepository() method without any relation or inheritance ..?

Comment: @dimo414...Okay I got it..Correct me if am wrong...In PlotManager...the method getPlotterRepository() is independent of method which is defined in DefaultRepositorySelector. But we are using a reference for getting return type of PlotterRepository in PlotManager...!!Right..? Secondly when we are calling repositorySelector.getPlotterRepository(); call is going first in interface repositorySelector then from there its going to where its fully defined and that is DefaultRepositorySelector..I'm right..?

Comment: I think you're overthinking this - the fact that the call is happening in `PlotManager` is irrelevant. You have a variable, `repositorySelector` of type `RepositorySelector`. This means that (as long as it's not `null`) the value of that variable is *some object* that implements `RepositorySelector`. And any object that implements that interface is required to have a `getPlotterRepository()` method that returns a `PlotterRepository`. When `repositorySelector.getPlotterRepository()` is called the method *on that object* is invoked.

Comment: You may want to read up on [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)) and other [features of object oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming#Features).

Answer (score 0):

```
static private RepositorySelector repositorySelector;
```

Some code that you have not shown, possibly in the constructor for `PlotManager`, or maybe in a dependency injection framework, initialized this variable with a reference to an instance of some other class (also not shown) that *implements* `RepositorySelector`.

In other words, there is a class somewhere that looks like this

```
public class RepositorySelectorImpl implements RepositorySelector {
   ...
   public PlotterRepository getPlotterRepository() {
       // do whatever the interface contract says
   }
   ...
}
```

and (probably) in the constructor for `PlotManager`

```
public PlotManager(...) {
    ...
    PlotManager.repositorySelector = new RepositorySelectorImpl();
    ...
}
```